# Cannot connect to emulator when IDEA and DDMS run in the same time

Tags: android, ubuntu, intellij-idea, ddms

When IntelliJ IDEA is open and I start DDMS, I get an error

[image]

So I opened DDMS options (File -> Options) and changed starting value for local port to 8800 and port of selected VM to 8900 (e.g. some other values than default ones).

[image]

I thought this would prevent this message as DDMS would connect to an emulator via a different port. However, I do not receive that error anymore, but I do not connect to the emulator, but I get some ???? processes instead.

[image: after]

Is there a way to have open IDEA and DDMS in the same time, connected to the same emulator?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to uncheck "Tools | Android | Enable ADB Service" in IDEA, then launch DDMS

Comment: This helps! Thanks. But now I have another question, what is the bad side (disadvantage) of unchecking "Enable ADB Service"?